# Нахождение чисел, составляющие сумму

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.5

Решаю очередную задачу с сайта codewars.

Имеется число `a` (предположим, `50`), нужно найти числа, квадраты которых в сумме дают `50` в  квадрате (числа меньше `а`, каждое должно быть больше другого)

Пример: `b**2 + c**2 + d**2 == a**2` при `a = 50` и `b < c < d`.

Пытался решить с помощью циклов, однако ничего не вышло. Прошу помочь мне с реализацией данного кода)

Comment: Так вы решаете задачу или спрашиваете, как её решить?

Comment: Я пытался решить самостоятельно, но мои попытки не увенчались успехом. В интренете про это я тоже ничего не нашел( Поэтому я обратился за помощью сюда.

Comment: Ну положим, при текущей формулировке задача решений не имеет (`b` больше `a`, `c` больше `b` - значит, левая сторона будет больше `2 * a^2` при любых значениях переменных). Где-то напутал в вопросе.

Comment: Может, `b < c < d`?

Comment: @hoefling Вы правы, прошу прощения за ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотя условий маловато (какое ограничение на числа? ноль, негативные числа допускаются? перестановки должны быть включены в ответ?), вот простая реализация бэктрекинга:

```
def combinations(a):
    for i in range(a):
        for j in range(i + 1, a):
            for k in range(j + 1, a):
                if i**2 + j**2 + k**2 == a**2:
                    yield i, j, k
```

Первый констрейнт варьируется в зависимости от условий задачи (если негативные числа включены, будет `range(-a, a)`, если ноль исключен, будет `range(1, a)` и т.д.):

```
def combinations(a):
    for i in range(-a, a):
        ...
```

Если нужны все комбинации, можно посчитать перестановки найденных кортежей:

```
def combinations(a):
    ...
    if i**2 + j**2 + k**2 == a**2:
        for p in itertools.permutations((i, j, k)):
            yield p
```

Тесты:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize('num, combs', (
    (0, []),
    (1, []),
    (2, []),
    (4, []),
    (5, [(0, 3, 4)]),
    (6, []),
    (7, [(2, 3, 6)]),
    (8, []),
    (9, [(1, 4, 8)]),
    (50, [(0, 14, 48), (0, 30, 40), (18, 24, 40), (24, 30, 32)]),
))
def test_combinations(num, combs):
    assert list(combinations(num)) == combs
```

Comment: Благодарю. Прошу простить меня за неправильную формулировку задачи, я новенький в данной сфере. Несколько озадачен словом "пермутации", не могли бы вы объяснить принцип действия данного метода?)

Comment: Да, правильный термин в русском - [перестановка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Если про устройство функции - в [доках](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) есть код и примеры использования.